# Extend basic alpine image to add dot net core app (Docker)

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have an alpine-based image that exposes a web server and does some work. I want to instantiate a container that runs that webserver and additionally I want to expose another web server inside the same container that runs my .net core app. So basically I want to create a new image by extending the first image and adding all the things that are needed to run my .net core app. All the documentation that I found on the internet shows how we can use **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1** as a runtime base image but I need an alpine-based image as a base image. So basically I need the docker file that extends alpine image to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1

Comment: There is an entire Microsoft documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-alpine

Answer (score 2):

The image tag you want is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-alpine`. This will give you .NET Core 3.1 on top of the latest version of Alpine. You can find a list of the supported tags at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet. You can also find a sample ASP.NET Core app's Dockerfile that uses Alpine at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.alpine-x64:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore -r linux-musl-x64

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /source/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained false --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine-amd64
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./

# See: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/20
# Uncomment to enable globalization APIs (or delete)
# ENV \
#     DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false \
#     LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
#     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs

ENTRYPOINT ["./aspnetapp"]
```